# Unable to import beautifulsoup4 module in Termux

Tags: python, termux

Here's the full log which shown that I'm unable to import `beautifulsoup4`

```
$ python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 23 2019, 08:30:10)
[Clang 8.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang b55f2d4ebfd35bf6 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import bs4
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup4' from 'bs4' (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py)

import beautifulsoup4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

Comment: pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: try installing beautiful soup first by typing the command @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη mentioned

Comment: Are you sure about characters case?

Comment: Thanks in advance. It (Termux) tells me that the beautifulsoup4 has been successfully installed.But I can't use beautifulsoup4.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```